# using .every to check if items in array are sequential

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use .every of Array to see if items in the array are sequential (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). Why does this return false when everything in it is true?

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

nums.every((num, index) => {
  if (index !== nums.length - 1) {
    console.log(num + 1 === nums[index + 1]);
    return num + 1 === nums[index + 1];
  }
});
```

Comment: Because for the final element `index === nums.length - 1` so it returns `undefined`, which is false-y.

Answer (score 6):

You're not returning anything on the last iteration, so the return value is `undefined`, which is falsey, so the `.every` will fail - return `true` in an `else`:

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(
  nums.every((num, index) => {
    if (index !== nums.length - 1) {
      console.log(num + 1 === nums[index + 1]);
      return num + 1 === nums[index + 1];
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  })
);
```

Or, without the `console.log`:

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(
  nums.every((num, index) => (
    index !== nums.length - 1
    ? num + 1 === nums[index + 1]
    : true
  ))
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would return `true` for the first element and then check the last item against the actual one.

Why the first element? It is easier to check. Compare

```
!index
```

vs

```
index !== array.length - 1
```

As you see the first check is shorter, compared to the second one.

```js
const
    nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    isInOrder =  nums.every((num, index, array) => {
        if (!index) return true;
        return array[index - 1] + 1 === num;
    });

console.log(isInOrder);
```

Comment: `nums.every((num, index, array) => !index || array[index - 1] + 1 === num);`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Anyways just for one-liner solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

On last iteration you return undefined. Try

```
nums.every( (x,i,a)=> x==a[0]+i )
```

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const numsBad = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5];

let test = arr => arr.every( (x,i,a)=> x==a[0]+i )

console.log(test(nums));
console.log(test(numsBad));
```